# Rearranging sections of lines of a file using regular expressions python

Tags: python, regex, string, csv, regex-group

so I am creating a script that will go through a file with a certain format and rearrange it to the same format as another file. Here is a sample of the unformatted file

```
, 0x40a846, mov [ecx+2bh],al, 88 41 2B, , , , \par
, 0x40a849, jmp $+001775cbh (0x581e14), E9 C6 75 17 00, , , , \par
, 0x40a84e, int3, CC, , , , \par
, 0x40a84f, int3, CC, , , , \par
, 0x40a850, push esi, 56, , , , \par
, 0x40a851, mov esi,ecx, 8B F1, , , , \par
```

the end goal is to have each line of the file looking like this

```
0x40a846, 0x 88 41 2B ,"mov [ecx+2bh],al",,,
```

My main issue is some lines of the file only have one section of source code while others have 2, making it difficult for me to make a regular expression that will grab both of them without grabbing the code bytes on accident. I wanted to use capture groups to rearrange the information on each line. Below is my script as of now:

```
import csv
import string
import re, sys
file_to_change = 'testingthecodexlconverter.csv'
    # = raw_input("Please specify what codexl file you would like to convert: ")
file1 = open(file_to_change, 'r+')

with file1  as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line[2:-12]
        line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',,'
       # mo = re.search(r'(.*?),.*?.*?,.*?(.*?),.*?.*?,.*?(.*?),.*?.*?,.*?(.*?)', line)
       #mo = re.search(r'(.*?),.*?(.*?,.*?.*?,).*?.*?,.*?(.*?),.*?.*?,.*?(.*?)', line)
        mo = re.search(r'(.*?),.*?(.*?.*?,\S*?,).*?.*?.*?,.*?(.*?),', line)  
        if mo:
            print(mo.group(2))
```

Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: Wanted to add, the script I included above will only print lines with more than one section of source code

Comment: are you sure regex is better than [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) in here?

Comment: [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits a given string into a list of words. You can access these list elements to rearrange each line of the file...

Comment: why do you import csv?

Comment: i started writing with the intention of using csv but forgot to delete it..and thanks albert!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize your lines as suggested by others by splitting at the commas and then just add them back when you print

```
file_to_change = 'testingthecodexlconverter.csv'

file1 = open(file_to_change, 'r+')

with file1  as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line[2:-12]

        tokens = line.split(',')

        # if column index 3 is empty then print without formatting for
        # unnecessary space.
        if not tokens[3]:
            print(tokens[0] + ", " + tokens[2].strip(" ") + ", " + tokens[1] + ",,,")
        else:
            print(tokens[0] + "," + tokens[3] +  ", " + tokens[2].strip(" ") + ", " + tokens[1] + ",,,")
```

this will print in the format:

```
0x40a846, 88 41 2B, al,  mov [ecx+2bh],,,
0x40a849, E9 C6 75 17 00,  jmp $+001775cbh (0x581e14),,,
0x40a84e, CC,  int3,,,
0x40a84f, CC,  int3,,,
0x40a850, 56,  push esi,,,
0x40a851, 8B F1, ecx,  mov esi,,,
```

Comment: you're welcome, also i noticed in my code i have an extra space before token[1]. You might want to take the space out of ", "  right before token[1]... not sure what your needs are, but it could affect parsing later if you have to do it again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pandas` and just rearrange the columns according to your need as it seems they are in a reasonable `csv` format. This method also allows you to visualise how you manipulate the data in your csv whilst you edit it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inputCSV.csv', header=None).fillna('')
df = df.astype(str)
out = df[[4,1,2]].to_csv(index=False, header=False, coding='utf-8', lineterminator='\r\n', mode='wb')
```

Your problem is a littler unclear in what data format you are exacting in each individual column.

I believe you might have missing comas in your input csv file. My suggestion is to do a search for these missing commas and add them to have a properly formatted input file.

The fastest way of course is by just splitting the string as mentioned above using `.split()` but it seems you are not sure what you are doing hence my suggestion of `pandas` for parsing.

Comment: I think, using [pandas IO tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for just reading and writing csv-files is kind of taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Nevermind, if you have pandas already installed on your system, but keep in mind that pandas is a relatively large python package. I'd rather suggest using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or python's standard [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv module, which you have already included, but aren't currently using.

```
import csv 

file_path = 'test.csv' 

with open(file_path) as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    writer = csv.writer(open('tempfile.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',') 
    for row in reader: 
        new_row = [e.strip() for e in row if len(e.strip()) > 0] 
        # The new row should have the first element, then the last,
        # followed by everything else that wasn't empty.
        new_row = [new_row[0], new_row[-1]] + new_row[1:-1] 
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

The new csv file looks like this:

```
0x40a846,88 41 2B,mov [ecx+2bh],al 
0x40a849,E9 C6 75 17 00,jmp $+001775cbh (0x581e14) 
0x40a84e,CC,int3
0x40a84f,CC,int3
0x40a850,56,push esi
0x40a851,8B F1,mov esi,ecx
```